# Change location of hibernate.properties file while using hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We provide db credential in hibernate.cfg.xml as

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">url</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <session-factory>
<hibernate-configuration>
```

Either we can provide these properties here or in hibernate.properties in classpath. But I want them to come from an external file. I couldn't find a way in hibernate to change the path of default hibernate.properties file.

Please help.

[EDIT]
The method in java which generates sessionFactory object

```
public class HibernateUtil {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    // Create the session factory from hibernate.cfg.xml
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder =
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryBuilder.build());
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the `sessionFactory` in your Java code.?

Answer (score 3):

**Programmatically, you can load XML and properties like this:**

```
public class MyHibernate {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        URL r1 = MyHibernate.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        Configuration c = new Configuration().configure(r1);

        try {
            InputStream is = MyHibernate.class.getResourceAsStream("/hibernate.properties");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(is);
            c.addProperties(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error reading properties", e);
        }

        return c.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        LOG.error("Error creating SessionFactory", ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

**Through Spring**

You can use a PropertiesFactoryBean to read-in the properties from your file and configure your LocalSessionFactoryBean:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location">path-to-properties-file</property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    ...
  </bean>
```

Hope it be useful.

Comment: I didn't want to use InputStream class to load hibernate properties, is there a way to include this in spring